# Using Google's Webkit Speech in ASP.NET aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech

I tried using the Google Webkit Speech API in my ASP.NET Aspx page using this:

```
<asp:TextBox class="chat-to-ai-textbox" ID="chatbox" runat="server" placeholder="Type or Speak"></asp:TextBox>
```

and added the code line:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      chatbox.Attributes.Add("x-webkit-speech", "x-webkit-speech");
}
```

I also added the following script to detect the browser support for Speech:

```
<script>
        if (document.createElement("input").webkitSpeech === undefined) {
            alert("Speech input is not supported in your browser.");
        }
</script>
```

However when running Chrome, I do not see a Speech button/option to start recognition and the browser displays my 'Not supported in your browser' error I scripted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> The x-webkit-speech input field attribute is deprecated. Please use the JavaScript API instead.

Use Github project for this purpose: https://github.com/Daniel-Hug/speech-input

Example :http://daniel-hug.github.io/speech-input/

**Use:**

Include speech-input.css and speech-input.js
Add an si-input class to your input field.
Wrap the input in a  with an si-wrapper class.
Add a button with an si-btn class as a sibling to the input. For the default style use the button markup in the example below:

```
<div class="si-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="si-input" placeholder="What's up?">
    <button class="si-btn">
        speech input
        <span class="si-mic"></span>
        <span class="si-holder"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: And does this support interim results? Do you know how to get the outputs interim results as well? The normal google api supports it.. which is to cycle through all recognized words real time. That effect you see on google speech